# Create and save three related tables at once cakephp 3.7

Tags: cakephp-3.0

[image: Tablas relacionadas]

In the add view of Volunteers, I have the forms of the 3 tables.
At the time of registration, I have problems with the 'contact_id' field in the People table.
They are created correctly, but I can not create a new form in the Contacts table, so that the cantacto_id field is different.
How can I save the 3 tables simultaneously?

Comment: When you say "registration", I assume you mean that it's a brand new contact; if that's wrong, please explain more about the situation. If I'm right, I think you'd need to save this as a contact, which has a person, which has a volunteer. What do your field names look like? For this structure you'd want to name fields like `direccion`, `persona.nombre` and `persona.voluntario.cv`.

Comment: Yes, "registration" is a new contact.
I'm just creating from Volunteers.
From the Volunteer controller, I can not get a new contact created.
Create Volunteer and Person, but it is still necessary to create a new Contact from the Voluntary controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your form, have fields like this:

```
echo $this->Form->input('direccion');
echo $this->Form->input('persona.nombre');
echo $this->Form->input('persona.voluntario.cv');
```

In your Volunteer controller, have code like this:

```
if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
    $contact_table = TableRegistry::get('Contactos');
    $contact = $contact_table->patchEntity($contact, $this->request->data, [
        'associated' => ['Personas' => ['Voluntarios']]
    ]);
    if ($contact_table->save($contact)) {
        // etc.
```

Comment: Register contact, but not Person or Volunteer.
The form is in the add view of Volunteer.

Comment: Apologies, the various table names need to be pluralized. I've corrected my code snippet above. If the names used here don't exactly match your tables and associations, you'll need to adjust it so they do. If it still doesn't work, please show the result of `debug($contact)` after the `patchEntity` call.

Comment: Hello again, I can not get the "Contact" data displayed in the Edit form. In the Edit view, it shows me the Volunteers and People data, but not the contacts data.
To bring the data, I must change "echo $ this-> Form-> input ('direccion');" by echo $ this-> Form-> input ('persona.contacto.direccion'); but by doing this the contact form is not saved.
What is the solution?

Comment: I think this should be posted as a separate question. You could reference this one there, and be sure to include the code you use when you read, patch and save the data in the `edit` function, and create the form in the template.